# How to select rows into columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the example below, how to fill the person_events table as shown?

What I have so far:

```sql
insert into person_events
select p.id, null, null, null, null, null, null
from persons p
```

Comment: Fix your data model!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need this new table `person_events`?

You already have the table `tickets` saving the relation between `person` and `events`. So you can use the following query to get the persons with the related event information:

```
SELECT p.ID, e.ID, e.date 
FROM tickets t 
   INNER JOIN person p ON t.person_id = p.ID 
   INNER JOIN events e ON t.event_id = e.ID
WHERE p.ID = 1
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dbdb6e7ab359ab5a73c6a7b6ef0ecbd3)

You also have to change the data on the `person_events` table everytime you change something on the `person` or `events` data. So using a simple query (like the above one) on a normalized database would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

your this method is missing 'values' in between,please your change query and please check it by running in sql before ask. its a simple question.

insert into person_events 
values
select p.id, null, null, null, null, null, null
from persons p

Comment: No, it is not missing 'values' because it's an insert select query.

Comment: yes my friend but you can not insert without using values in between insert and select. so please recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create a person_events tabel?
If you do something like

```
SELECT tickets.person_id, events.id, events.date
FROM tickets INNER JOIN events on ( events.id = tickets.event_id )
```

Doesn't this have the outcome you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into person_events
select p.id
    ,1
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN event_id = 1 then e.date end)
    ,2
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN event_id = 2 then e.date end)
    ,3
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN event_id = 3 then e.date end)
from persons p
JOIN tickets t ON t.person_id = p.id
JOIN events e ON t.event_id = e.id
GROUP BY p.id
```